# Why won't my application install on simulator or device iOS xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

When trying to build and run my application I get the following error

```
Details

Failed to install the requested application
Domain: NSPOSIXErrorDomain
Code: 22
Failure Reason: The bundle identifier of the application could not be determined.
Recovery Suggestion: Ensure that the application's Info.plist contains a value for CFBundleIdentifier.
User Info: {
    bundleURL = "file:///Users/davidhouse/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Pikit-evrjzcfwqbcrxwfgrnarwlnvwoli/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Pikit.app/";
}
--


System Information

macOS Version 10.15.5 (Build 19F101)
Xcode 11.5 (16139)
```

Here is my info.plist:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>$(DEVELOPMENT_LANGUAGE)</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_PACKAGE_TYPE)</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>1.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>1</string>
    <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
    <string>${PRODUCT_NAME} needs access to your camera to share your ideas with friends</string>
    <key>UIApplicationSceneManifest</key>
    <dict>
        <key>UIApplicationSupportsMultipleScenes</key>
        <false/>
        <key>UISceneConfigurations</key>
        <dict>
            <key>UIWindowSceneSessionRoleApplication</key>
            <array>
                <dict>
                    <key>UISceneConfigurationName</key>
                    <string>Default Configuration</string>
                    <key>UISceneDelegateClassName</key>
                    <string>$(PRODUCT_MODULE_NAME).SceneDelegate</string>
                    <key>UISceneStoryboardFile</key>
                    <string>Main</string>
                </dict>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
    <string>LaunchScreen</string>
    <key>UIMainStoryboardFile</key>
    <string>Main</string>
    <key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
    <array>
        <string>armv7</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

As you can see there is an entry for `CFBundleIdentifier`. The app was installing and running earlier and I had made no changes to the plist.

I have tried running the App on both a simulation(iPhone 11 pro) and a real device(iPad mini) both of which worked previously.

I have tried running clean build folder, restarting xcode, removing and reinstalling my pod file deleting and recreating my plist, deleting the DerivedData folder and rebuilding, and updating my computer all without success. Any help would be greatly appreciated, and please let me know if I can provide anymore information.

After recreating my project from scratch I was able to get it running on the simulator, however it is still not installing on my actual device. Here is the error that I am getting:

```
Details

Unable to install "Pikit"
Domain: com.apple.dt.MobileDeviceErrorDomain
Code: -402653103
--
Could not inspect the application package.
Domain: com.apple.dt.MobileDeviceErrorDomain
Code: -402653103
User Info: {
    DVTRadarComponentKey = 282703;
    MobileDeviceErrorCode = "(0xE8000051)";
    "com.apple.dtdevicekit.stacktrace" = (
    0   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x000000011f36581a DTDKCreateNSErrorFromAMDErrorCode + 233
    1   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x000000011f3a6f70 __90-[DTDKMobileDeviceToken installApplicationBundleAtPath:withOptions:andError:withCallback:]_block_invoke + 155
    2   DVTFoundation                       0x0000000106230155 DVTInvokeWithStrongOwnership + 73
    3   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x000000011f3a6ca8 -[DTDKMobileDeviceToken installApplicationBundleAtPath:withOptions:andError:withCallback:] + 1654
    4   IDEiOSSupportCore                   0x000000011f21de91 __118-[DVTiOSDevice(DVTiPhoneApplicationInstallation) processAppInstallSet:appUninstallSet:installOptions:completionBlock:]_block_invoke.352 + 4165
    5   DVTFoundation                       0x00000001063637f4 __DVT_CALLING_CLIENT_BLOCK__ + 7
    6   DVTFoundation                       0x0000000106365436 __DVTDispatchAsync_block_invoke + 1194
    7   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff70bee6c4 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
    8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff70bef658 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff70bf4c44 _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 597
    10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff70bf55d6 _dispatch_lane_invoke + 363
    11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff70bfec09 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 596
    12  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff70e4da3d _pthread_wqthread + 290
    13  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff70e4cb77 start_wqthread + 15
);
}
--


System Information

macOS Version 10.15.5 (Build 19F101)
Xcode 11.5 (16139)
```

Comment: Had you got the solution ?

Answer (score -1):

I can replicate the issue and getting the same error. 
[image]

To solve this search for **PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER** in the build settings of the target and add a value there. Like below

[image]

Clean all and build. Hope will work.

Comment: Hello Niladri, thank you for your reply. I have already ensured that this has a value, however I still get the error. I have updated my question.